# How Can I modify my existing function to return data to a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I am coding a view controller that gets a JSON array of latest released films and displays them in the class. I have the rest of the code working with a static object but im new to handling json data and returning it from a function. Below is my working function and I need to return the data to a variable that is accessible by other function.
Any Help Is Much appreciated

```swift
func latestMovieReleases()
    {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: latestReleasesURL!) {(data, response, error) in
        do
            {
                let movies = try JSONDecoder().decode([latestReleasesJSON].self, from: data!)

                for movie in movies
                {
                    print(movie.title)
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("We Got An Error :- ")
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Here is the struct that is located in my structures file

```swift
struct latestReleasesJSON: Decodable
{
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let posterurl: String
    let year: String
    let releaseDate: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func latestMovieReleases(completion:@escaping([latestReleasesJSON]? -> ()))
{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: latestReleasesURL!) {(data, response, error) in

      guard let data = data else {completion(nil) ; return } 
      do
        {
            let movies = try JSONDecoder().decode([latestReleasesJSON].self, from: data)

            for movie in movies
            {
                print(movie.title)
            }

            completion(movies)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("We Got An Error :- ")
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Call

```
 latestMovieReleases { (res) in
    if let re = res {
      print(re)
    }
 }
```

---

```
struct latestReleasesJSON: Decodable {
  let id,title,posterurl,year,releaseDate: String 
}
```

Comment: You know this is duplicate.